# Flair not updating after spending well earned unicorns on Rep to the Max Power-Up

Tags: support, bug, flair, unicoins

After buying the Reputation to the Max Power-Up I have gained a significant amount of Reputation, ofcourse I now want to show my great amount of reputation to all my friends and family but as you can see below my flair still has my low reputation. If I show this flair to my family they will laugh at me so what can I do to show my new well earned reputation? =O

[image: profile for Daanvn at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

As you can see on my profile I clearly have more reputation:

[image]

My parents promised me that if I ever got over 6.000rep they would pay me a trip to the magical unicorn valley so pls help me!
[image]

Comment: Photoshop is your friend.

Comment: oh this has to be a bug, hope they fix it before April 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably caching... try again tomorrow - the cache probably will have cleared by then...